# Как инициализировать массив `std::array` с помощью `std::initializer_list`?

Tags: c++, массивы, c++11

Как инициализировать массив `std::array` с помощью `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Using std::array with initialization lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8192185/4279)

Answer (score 6):

Стандартный класс `std::array` является агрегатом. Из стандарта C++ (23.3.2 Class template array)

> 2 An array is an aggregate...

Поэтому его нельзя инициализировать с помощью объекта `std::initializer_list`. Вы можете лишь копировать значения из объекта типа `std::initializer_list` в объекты класса `std::array`. Ниже показан пример, как это можно сделать

Ниже показано, как это можно сделать для члена данных класса.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    struct A
    {
        A(std::initializer_list<int> lst)
        {
            std::copy(lst.begin(),
                std::next(lst.begin(), std::min(lst.size(), a.size())),
                a.begin());
        }
        std::array<int, 5> a;
    } obj{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for (int x : obj.a) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Так как число инициализаторов для объекта `std::array` может оказаться меньше, чем элементов в объекте, то, чтобы соответствовать нормам стандарта C++, оставшиеся без инициализаторов элементы так же желательно инициализировать. Для скалярных фундаментальных типов это инициализация 0.

Поэтому будет более правильно будет записать конструктор класса следующим образом

```
A(std::initializer_list<int> lst)
{
    auto it = std::copy(lst.begin(),
        std::next(lst.begin(), std::min(lst.size(), a.size())),
            a.begin());
    std::fill(it, a.end(), 0);
}
```

добавив вызов алгоритма `std::fill`

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, не совсем понятна цель ... Можно же потом заполнить. Если всеж хочется одним оператором, можно лямбдой воспользоваться:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
  std::initializer_list<int> Init = {1,2,3,4,5,6};  

  // вариант 1  
  std::array<int,6> Array1;
  std::copy(Init.begin(),Init.end(),Array1.begin());

  // вариант 2
  std::array<int, 6> Array2 = [&]() {
    std::array<int, 6> Values = { 0 };
    std::copy(Init.begin(),Init.end(),Values.begin());
    return Values;
  }();  

  for(const auto &i:Array1) std::cout << i << " "; std::cout << std::endl;    
  for(const auto &i:Array2) std::cout << i << " "; std::cout << std::endl;    
  return 0;
}
```

[На ideone](http://ideone.com/UVWqIM).

Answer (score 1):

Исключительно ради хохмы. Чтобы инициализировать `std::array` с помощью `std::initializer_list` нужно чтобы `std::array` содержал `std::initializer_list`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::initializer_list<int>, 2> a = 
        { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } } };

    for( auto e : a ) { 
        for( auto i: e ) {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Тест](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/N7g0fM1pJttNbNny)</kbd>